# how to call global variables within the same function

Tags: python

I want to use the global variables in and outside of the function, but there is an error with calling `usingDesired` in the print statements

```
def getTargetPage():

    global usingDesired
    global usingNotChecked

    while True:

        desiredPages = open(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\desired_pages.txt', "r")
        pagesNotChecked = open(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\pages_not_checked.txt', "r")

        if os.path.getsize(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\pages_not_checked.txt') == 0:
            fileReader = open(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\desired_pages.txt', "r")
            usingDesired = True

        if os.path.getsize(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\pages_not_checked.txt') > 0:
            fileReader = open(r'C:\Users\tree3\Desktop\Instagram\pages_not_checked.txt', "r")
            usingNotChecked = True

        print(usingDesired)
        print(usingNotChecked)
```

Comment: Show the error.

Comment: @Ouroborus line 58, in getTargetPage
    print(usingDesired)
NameError: name 'usingDesired' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare a variable usingDesired globally without global keyword.
Inside function you can manipulate this variable as below

```
global usingDesired
usingDesired = 'udpate global variable value'
```